Why is my MongoDB container not in my Docker container and viewable by Studio 3T
My goal is to be able to use Studio 3T to view my "users" collection in my dbTrial database in docker as I develop my code. In an earlier project, I executed the command docker run -p 27017:27017 --name trial_mongo -d mongo. Then, I ran npm install mongodb. Then I used url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017 in the code. I created a "customers" collection which currently shows in Studio 3T.
In my current project, I'm using the same database as above, dbTrial, and successfully reading from and writing to a "users" collection. The "users" collection does not show in my dockers container in Studio 3T. So I have no idea where the collection or database I'm using in this code actually reside. There are no local instances of MongoDB running. Perhaps my code currently running is successfully reading from and writing to a database, dbTrial, stored locally even though no active mongo session exists on my local computer. How do make my "users" collection reside in my docker container and be viewable by Studio 3T? More, importantly how do I find my database and my "users" collection on my computer? The below code snippet illustrates how I connect to the database:
const { MongoClient } = require("mongodb"); const url = "mongodb://localhost:27017"; let db = null; const connectToMongoDB = async () => { try { console.log("Attempting to connect to MongoDB..."); const client = await MongoClient.connect(url); console.log("Connected to MongoDB!"); db = client.db("dbTrial"); } catch (err) { console.error(`Error connecting to MongoDB: ${err}`); throw new Error(`Failed to connect to MongoDB: ${err.message}`); } }; const create = async (name, email, password) => { const collection = db.collection("users");
I ran ps -xa | grep mongodb expecting to find an active MongoDB process and found none. I've searched google for the default location of MongoDB database when MongoDB was installed by npm on a Mac and have not been able to find /data/db anywhere. I also ran global searches for bson file types i.e. find / -name "*.bson" 2>/dev/null and for mongod.config i.e. find -name "mongod.config" 2>/dev/null and found nothing.

Unbelievable. Right clicking the database in Studio 3T and selecting "Refresh All" made both collections visible.
